# How to use ":nth-child()" in a loop with complex querySelector()

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, queryselector

Extracting data into a single array with `querySelector` works:

```js
var don1 = [];
var don2 = [];
var don3 = [];
var num = 3;

function getData(num) {

  for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {

    let y = eval("don" + i.toString());
    console.log("checkpoint " + i + ": y = " + y);

    y[0] = document.querySelector(
      "[data-dynamic='project.ProjectCode']"
    ).innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "");

    y[1] = document.querySelector(
      "[data-react-component-name='DonationAmount'] input[type='text']"
    ).value;

    y[2] = document.querySelector(
      "[data-react-component-name='Frequency'] > select"
    ).options[
      document.querySelector(
        "[data-react-component-name='Frequency'] > select"
      ).selectedIndex
    ].text;
    console.log("checkpoint " + i + ": y = " + y);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button1" onclick="getData(3)" type="button"> getData </button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<div data-component="cart.populated">
  <div data-component="cart.populated.project">
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        PROJ 1
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$50.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        101
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        Erica
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$20.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        102
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        Allison
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$10.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        103
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Extracting data into multiple arrays using `:nth-child` doesn't seem to work:

```js
var don1 = [];
var don2 = [];
var don3 = [];
var num = 3;

function getData(num) {

  for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {

    let y = eval("don" + i.toString());
    console.log("checkpoint " + i + ": y = " + y);

    y[0] = document
      .querySelector("[data-dynamic='project.ProjectCode']:nth-child(" + i + ")")
      .innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "");

    y[1] = document.querySelector(
      "[data-react-component-name='DonationAmount'] input[type='text']:nth-child(" + i + ")").value;

    y[2] = document.querySelector(
      "[data-react-component-name='Frequency'] > select:nth-child(" + i + ")").options[
      document.querySelector(
        "[data-react-component-name='Frequency'] > select:nth-child(" + i + ")").selectedIndex
    ].text;
    console.log("checkpoint " + i + ": y = " + y);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button1" onclick="getData(3)" type="button"> getData </button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<div data-component="cart.populated">
  <div data-component="cart.populated.project">
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        PROJ 1
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$50.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        101
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        Erica
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$20.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        102
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <label>
        Allison
      </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        Donation Amount:
      </label>

      <span data-react-component-name="DonationAmount">
        <input type="text" value="$10.00" maxlength="10">
      </span>

      <span data-react-component-name="Frequency">
        <select>
          <option value="O">One Time</option>
          <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <label data-dynamic="project.ProjectCode">
        103
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without seeing your HTML structure and elements

Comment: Where is your markup? Your `eval()` function?

Comment: @ZachJensz `eval()` is built-in and it's use by novices is discouraged because of it's potential danger.

Comment: @zer00ne Oh wow yeah I forgot it existed, never use it xD super dangerous

Comment: If you have the ability to assign: `data-react-component-name='DonationAmount'` to a tag...why can't you assign something like this: `class='simple'` to a tag?

Comment: @cheesyMan That makes sense! I've added the html so you can see it

Comment: @ZachJensz what is dangerous about it? Yes, I am a novice

Comment: @zer00ne this might be possible, I didn't think of this because I have limited access to the structure. The org I work for uses a donor software that created their own designer (very annoying). I'll try it and get back.

Comment: @zer00ne What's a better method to use the "i" in the loop through each of those variables!

Comment: @zer00ne if I was able to use class="simple", how would I add nth-child() using 'i' as the child identifier, like this: document.querySelector(".simple:nth-child(" + i +")"); or is there some other way to use that?

Comment: Hi @LukeHerron I just took a closer look at your HTML and saw that your targeting form controls (`<input>`,  and `<select>` specifically). Does the layout repeat itself? As in are there multiple `<input>`s and `<select>`s wrapped in `<span>`?

Comment: @zer00ne yes, it's a shopping cart page, and there can be numerous instances of each grouping. In the above HTML there are 3 gifts, but there could be more or less depending on the user. The gift has several components, amount, project number, and frequency, and each of these components has it's own <span></span> containing it.

Comment: Ok did you want access to all of the form controls? Or do you need access to the form controls that the user clicks? Or...?

Comment: @zer00ne Honestly, think if I can figure out the solution to this problem, I think I'll be able to solve the problem
 if I was able to use class="simple", how would I add nth-child() using 'i' as the child identifier? like this?  document.querySelector(".simple:nth-child(" + i +")"). Or is there some other way to use that?

Comment: Yeah, most definitely are better solutions, but it depends on if you need multiple tags, and where they are, and how your layout is.